# Facebook fql case insensitive version of strpos

Tags: api, facebook, case-insensitive, facebook-fql, strpos

What is the case insensitive version of

```
strpos(field', 'Phrase')
```

in facebook query language?

Comment: This works: strpos(lower(field), 'phrase') > 0. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your closest bet would be to convert both phrases to lowercase (or uppercase) for the comparison, as follows:

```
strpos(lower(field),lower(phrase))
```

Comment: I just thought there would be something like stripos, similar to in php. ANyway - old trick ;-) thx

Comment: You would think so, but it wasn't even in PHP until 5. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

Try stripos, case insensitive strpos

https://www.php.net/stripos

Comment: That's not an option in facebook's fql